# Image fading animation when anchor link clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, fade, fadein, fadeout

I'm totally new to jquery and I didn't find exactly what I wanted so I've written it by myself. The goal is to create an image fading animations (from image A to image B) when the link above is clicked.

Anyways, its behavior is not what I would except .. it isn't smooth enough when clicking quickly / randomly. Could you please say a word about it? Thank you!

**THIS IS THE RUNNING EXAMPLE:**

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NvsLL/1/)

CSS:

```
...
.overlappingImage {position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:none}
...
```

The code:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">

        function FadeToImage(event, to_image_name, speed) {

        if (event != null)
            event.preventDefault();

        var currentImgWrapper = $("#dummy");

        var currentImg = currentImgWrapper.find('img');
        if (currentImg != null) currentImg.removeClass("overlappingImage");

        var newImgHTML = '<div id="dummy">' + '<img id="to_upper_image" src="' + to_image_name + '" class="overlappingImage"/>' + '</div>';

        if (currentImgWrapper.html() == null)
            $("#d").html(newImgHTML);
        else $("#d").html(currentImgWrapper.html() + newImgHTML);

        currentImgWrapper.fadeOut(speed);
        $("#to_upper_image").fadeIn(speed);

        $("#to_upper_image").removeAttr('id');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        FadeToImage(null, 'img/1.JPG', 0);            

        $('a').first().click(function(event) {
            FadeToImage(event, 'img/2.JPG', 1000);
        });

        $('a').last().click(function(event) {

            FadeToImage(event, 'img/3.JPG', 1000);
        });

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">CLICK 1</a> <a href="#">CLICK 2</a>
    <div id="d" style="position: relative; margin: 50px">
    </div>
</body>
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the animation smoother, you should only execute subsequent fades after each one is finished:

```
currentImgWrapper.fadeOut(speed, function() {
    $("#to_upper_image").fadeIn(speed)
                        .removeAttr('id');
});
```